# Create continous plot using matplotlib/seaborn with specific hue

Tags: plotting, seaborn

df.head()=

```
day SBP     exercise
0   146.0   False
1   149.0   False
2   146.0   True
3   148.0   False
4   149.0   False
5   149.0   False
```

i am looking to plot `day` vs `sbp` with each data point coloured as per `exercise`.
i used following command but couldn't get each point colored as per exercise:
`plt.plot('user','SBP', color='green', linestyle='dashed', marker='o',data=df)`

can anyone help how i should go about this..?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this plot?

The code for doing it is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

day=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
SBP=[146.0, 149.0, 146.0, 148.0, 149.0, 149.0]
exercise=[False, False, True, False, False, False]

plt.scatter(day, SBP, c=exercise, s=50)
plt.xlabel("Day")
plt.ylabel("SBP")
plt.show()
```

The color of each point is already specified in the array "exercise", so you have only to let matplotlib point to it.

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: WHat i am looking for is those dots connected to each other..there should a dotted line between two consecutive points irrespective to exercise variable

Comment: As far as I know, matplotlib does not foresee such functionality. But as workaround, you can draw another plot on top of this one. Speaking in code, you can add `plt.plot(day, SBP, '--')` just after the plt.scatter line